# How to retrieve a custom tab using the terminal command?

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-tab

I need to retrieve the new custom tab I've created in Salesforce.
How should I format a tab name in the sfdx command, based on the tab label, I need to retrieve a specific tab that I've created in salesforce using the command in the terminal, I'm trying the following and it says No results found,

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomTab:Commerce_Buffer__c.tab-meta.xml
```

Tab Label is

> Commerce Buffres

I need to retrieve this so I can commit to the repo, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just the API name of the tab. You can check Setup to see what its supposed to be, but the default is just the object API name.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomTab:Commerce_Buffer__c
```

Tabs not belonging to objects will not have this suffix:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomTab:Commerce_Buffer
```

Comment: It's so strange that it still doesn't find it, I'm still getting no result found. In the setup->tabs, I can see my tab called Commerce Buffers with the (s) and when I click on it, I can see the label is the same and the object is my Commerce Buffer object. I think I'm doing everything correct.

Comment: @Bahman.A Finally got home, I had a chance to test it. It really is supposed to be with the suffix if it's an object tab, otherwise not.

Comment: I'm hoping that you've had a great day so far. I just saw your updated answer. 
 using the singular with __c suffix worked!
 Thanks a lot for your help.